# Google maps api key for android pricing

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This question may sound very basic but please bear with me. In Android [developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start), it is stated that :

> Your application needs an API key to access the Google Maps servers. The type of key you need is an API key with restriction for Android apps. The key is free. You can use it with any of your applications that call the Maps SDK for Android, and it supports an unlimited number of users.

Is it applicable to commercial apps also. For example famous apps like the big ride-sharing unicorns ("uber", "ola") who use google maps in their android apps don't pay anything to google?

Comment: It depends on how much request can be done. It is mentioned in google official document if you read. If it cross the request it will ask for pricing.

Comment: Have a look at [this.](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-limits) and [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/previous-pricing)

Comment: Uber and Grab certainly pay a royalty to Google.  For development purposes, the free daily quota you will get will probably be enough for you.  If you launch, and end up with the problem of having to pay Google, then I view it as a good thing, because it means your app is taking off.